# Can we pass extra Data with action_get_content intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I want this passed extra variable in OnActivityResult() of the activity.

```
intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.putExtra("question_id",getArguments().getInt(QUESTION_POSITION));
startActivityForResult(intent, GALLERY);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.putExtra("question_id",getArguments().getInt(QUESTION_POSITION));
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,GALLERY);
```

Comment: Hope this may help you

Comment: Sorry,I didn't test it out.I found another way out.I am not sure but in general is it a good practice to pass extra data with system defined Intents.

Answer (score 0):

Sending Image from one Activity to another Activity

```
private String selectedImagePath = "";
final private int PICK_IMAGE = 1;
final private int CAPTURE_IMAGE = 2;

 public Uri setImageUri() {
    // Store image in dcim
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/DCIM/", "image" + new Date().getTime() + ".png");
    Uri imgUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    this.imgPath = file.getAbsolutePath();
    return imgUri;
}


public String getImagePath() {
    return imgPath;
}

btnGallery.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, ""), PICK_IMAGE);

        }
    });

    btnCapture.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, setImageUri());
            startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE);
        }
    });

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE) {
            selectedImagePath = getAbsolutePath(data.getData());
            imgUser.setImageBitmap(decodeFile(selectedImagePath));
        } else if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE) {
            selectedImagePath = getImagePath();
            imgUser.setImageBitmap(decodeFile(selectedImagePath));
        } else {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }

}


 public Bitmap decodeFile(String path) {
    try {
        // Decode image size
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, o);
        // The new size we want to scale to
        final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 70;

        // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
        int scale = 1;
        while (o.outWidth / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE && o.outHeight / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE)
            scale *= 2;

        // Decode with inSampleSize
        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize = scale;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, o2);
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;

}

public String getAbsolutePath(Uri uri) {
    String[] projection = { MediaColumns.DATA };
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null) {
        int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaColumns.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    } else
        return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.putExtra("question_id",getArguments().getInt(QUESTION_POSITION));
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivityForResult(intent, GALLERY);
```